# Insert all values of a table into another table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to insert all values of one table into another. But the insert statement accepts values, but i would like it to accept a select * from the initial_Table. Is this possible?

Answer (score 301, accepted):

The insert statement actually has a syntax for doing just that. It's a lot easier if you specify the column names rather than selecting "*" though:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (Foo, Bar, Fizz, Buzz)
SELECT Foo, Bar, Fizz, Buzz
FROM initial_table
-- optionally WHERE ...
```

I'd better clarify this because for some reason this post is getting a few down-votes.

The INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM syntax is for when the table you're inserting into ("new_table" in my example above) already exists. As others have said, the SELECT ... INTO syntax is for when you want to create the new table as part of the command.

You didn't specify whether the new table needs to be created as part of the command, so INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM should be fine if your destination table already exists.

Comment: Wha--? Someone wanna leave me a comment explaining why this post is generating down-votes? I don't see anything in the OPs question that specifies that the new table should be created as part of the query.

Comment: How does this handle integrity constraint violations? For example, if a unique is duplicated does it stop the query or just skip that particular entry?

Comment: I believe it'll throw an error and roll back the transaction, meaning nothing gets copied. Worth testing though.

Answer (score 40):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO newTable SELECT * FROM initial_Table
```

Comment: Not work when using stars when we have identity column

Comment: For this scenario with identity add SET IDENTITY_INSERT table_name ON first and the same with off at the end to insert the identity values.

Answer (score 14):

You can insert using a Sub-query as follows:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (columns....)
SELECT columns....
FROM initial_table where column=value
```

Answer (score 13):

From [here:](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_select_into.asp)

```
SELECT *
INTO new_table_name [IN externaldatabase] 
FROM old_tablename
```

Comment: This creates a new table. He already has an existing table.

Answer (score 6):

There is an easier way where you don't have to type any code (Ideal for Testing or One-time updates):

> Step 1

- Right click on table in the explorer and select "Edit top 100 rows";

> Step 2

- Then you can select the rows that you want (*Ctrl + Click* or *Ctrl + A*), and Right click and Copy 
  (**Note**: If you want to add a "*where*" condition,  then Right Click on Grid -> Pane -> SQL
  Now you can edit Query and add WHERE condition, then Right Click again ->  Execute SQL, your required rows will be available to select on bottom)

> Step 3

- Follow Step 1 for the target table.

> Step 4

- Now go to the end of the grid and the last row will have an asterix *(*)* in first column (This row is to add new entry). Click on that to select that entire row and then PASTE (*Ctrl + V*). The cell might have a Red Asterix (indicating that it is not saved)

> Step 5

- Click on any other row to trigger the insert statement (the Red Asterix will disappear)

**Note - 1**: If the columns are not in the correct order as in Target table, you can always follow Step 2, and Select the Columns in the same order as in the Target table

**Note - 2** - If you have Identity columns then execute `SET IDENTITY_INSERT sometableWithIdentity ON` and then follow above steps, and in the end execute `SET IDENTITY_INSERT sometableWithIdentity OFF`

Answer (score 3):

If you are transferring a lot data permanently, i.e not populating a temp table, I would recommend using **SQL Server Import/Export Data** for table-to-table mappings.

Import/Export tool is usually better than straight SQL when you have type conversions and possible value truncation in your mapping. Generally, the more complex your mapping, the more productive you are using an ETL tool like Integration Services (SSIS) instead of direct SQL.

Import/Export tool is actually an SSIS wizard, and you can save your work as a dtsx package.

Answer (score 2):

I think this statement might do what you want.

```
INSERT INTO newTableName (SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM oldTable);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
                ofd.Filter = "*.mdb|*.MDB"
                ofd.FilterIndex = (2)
                ofd.FileName = "bd1.mdb"
                ofd.Title = "SELECCIONE LA BASE DE DATOS ORIGEN (bd1.mdb)"
                ofd.ShowDialog()
                Dim conexion1 = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" + ofd.FileName
                Dim conn As New OdbcConnection()
                conn.ConnectionString = conexion1
                conn.Open()



            'EN ESTE CODIGO SOLO SE AGREGAN LOS DATOS'
            Dim ofd2 As New OpenFileDialog
            ofd2.Filter = "*.mdb|*.MDB"
            ofd2.FilterIndex = (2)
            ofd2.FileName = "bd1.mdb"
            ofd2.Title = "SELECCIONE LA BASE DE DATOS DESTINO (bd1.mdb)"
            ofd2.ShowDialog()
            Dim conexion2 = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" + ofd2.FileName
            Dim conn2 As New OdbcConnection()
            conn2.ConnectionString = conexion2
            Dim cmd2 As New OdbcCommand
            Dim CADENA2 As String

            CADENA2 = "INSERT INTO EXISTENCIA IN '" + ofd2.FileName + "' SELECT * FROM EXISTENCIA IN '" + ofd.FileName + "'"


            cmd2.CommandText = CADENA2
            cmd2.Connection = conn2
            conn2.Open()
            Dim dA2 As New OdbcDataAdapter
            dA2.SelectCommand = cmd2
            Dim midataset2 As New DataSet
            dA2.Fill(midataset2, "EXISTENCIA")
```