# Postgres 9.5 CREATE TABLE LIKE INCLUDING ALL NO FK Constraints?

Tags: postgresql

I am attempting to copy some tables in my Postgres database using `like_options` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtable.html), which states that using `INCLUDING ALL` is shorthand for copying CONSTRAINTS as well (info for queries found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284514/how-do-i-copy-data-from-one-table-to-another-in-postgres-using-copy-command) and looking up FKs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152260/postgres-sql-to-list-table-foreign-keys#1152321)

> INCLUDING ALL is an abbreviated form of INCLUDING DEFAULTS INCLUDING
>   CONSTRAINTS INCLUDING INDEXES INCLUDING STORAGE INCLUDING COMMENTS.

However, I am not seeing the expected FK-constraint from the original table after I run the copy - ***assuming that because the new table is empty I cannot add a FK-constraint referencing a column in another table?***

```
create table lobby (LIKE command_center INCLUDING ALL);


SELECT
    tc.constraint_name, tc.table_name, kcu.column_name, 
    ccu.table_name AS foreign_table_name,
    ccu.column_name AS foreign_column_name 
FROM 
    information_schema.table_constraints AS tc 
    JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
      ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
    JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
      ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
WHERE constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND (tc.table_name='command_center' OR tc.table_name='lobby');
```

[image: Original FK Constraint after table copy no new FK Constraint]

Comment: The manual explicitly states the things that **are** copied. The consequence of that is that anything not listed in the manual is **not** copied - which means FK constraints are excluded.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong btw. An empty table can absolutely have foreign keys.