# how to: insert into, select - but one field is from somewhere else?

Tags: sql-server, select, insert

this is how insert into, select is usually working
(example taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/576442/101055):

```
INSERT INTO new_table (Foo, Bar, Fizz, Buzz)
SELECT Foo, Bar, Fizz, Buzz
FROM initial_table
```

**BUT - how to do this if `Fizz` is not in the initial_table, but is a variable `@fizz`?**

this *fails*:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (Foo, Bar, @fizz, Buzz)
SELECT Foo, Bar, Buzz
FROM initial_table
```

thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO new_table (Foo, Bar, Fizz, Buzz)
SELECT Foo, Bar, @fizz, Buzz
FROM initial_table
```

The insert syntax is

```
insert into destination_table (destination_colum1, destination_colum2, ...)
select source_value1, source_value2, ...  from source_table
```

First you name the columns you want to write into **and then** you select the source

Comment: thnx. that DOES work. can you tell me why? i thought if i am doing SELECT Foo, Bar, @fizz, Buzz FROM initial_table that it will try and take it from the initial_table and didn't even try it :( will accept the answer anyhow in 12 minutes that i must wait. thnx again