# Sql temp table with except

Tags: sql, join, except, temp-tables

I am trying to insert the records that come of this query into a temp table. Any help or suggestion will be helpful

```
insert into #AddRec
select *
from stg di
right join
ED bp
on
bp.ID = di.ID
except
select *
from stg di
inner join
ED bp
on
bp.ID = di.ID
```

Comment: #AddRec is it a tablename with # ?

Comment: can you post a little more information - which database server sql server 2012? what is the schema of #AddRec and of the other 2 tables

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656088/how-to-insert-into-select-but-one-field-is-from-somewhere-else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6cc36/3) may help it simplifies your query a little.

```
create table #AddRec(id int) ;

insert into #addrec
select  ed.id
from stg right join 
ed on stg.id=ed.id 
where stg.id is null;

select * from #Addrec
```

If you need more fields from the tables add the definitions into the temp table and add them into the select line

Comment: Thank you Ian, learnt something new I dont have to use the except. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH Q AS
(
select *
from stg di
right join
ED bp
on
bp.ID = di.ID
except
select *
from stg di
inner join
ED bp
on
bp.ID = di.ID 
)
INSERT INTO #AddRec(... list of fields ...)
SELECT (... list of fields ...) FROM Q
```

if you want to create the temp table from scratch, just replace the insert with:

```
SELECT (... list of fields ...) 
INTO #AddRec
FROM Q
```

Answer (score 0):

if   your select return matches the field count of insert table this should work!

```
  insert into tbl1 (field1,field2)
    select field1,field2 from.................
```

Answer (score 0):

easiest way

```
select *
into #AddRec
from stg di
right join ED bp on bp.ID = di.ID
except
select * from stg di
inner join ED bp on bp.ID = di.ID
```

Comment: it will be much better if you can elaborate on what exactly your code is doing.

Comment: Also, note that this question is nearly 8 years old. How does your answer improve upon the other three?