# Why is my query is not able to select form one table then insert into another table?

Tags: mysql

I have two different tables, users and complaint. I want to select values from tables users and insert it into tables complaint.

Table users:

```
username | name | password|
```

Table complaint:

```
complaint_ID| name | date|
```

This what I have tried:

```
$query_search = "INSERT INTO complaint (name) SELECT (name) FROM users";
```

Comment: Your query looks okey what is the problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576441/insert-all-values-of-a-table-into-another-table-in-sql    check this question this is the same you have asked

Comment: wait i paste the error ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use your primary key for fetching data, for retrieving the value from your table users, write a query like:

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE password=(...);
```

And then add this data in your second table complain write a query:

```
UPDATE complain SET name=(.....) WHERE complaint_ID=(....);
```