# Mapping between two table data

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
table1:
name,
address,
phone


table2:
name,
location,
mobile
```

`table1` is a just a schema of blank data. `table2` has data.

I would like to insert `table2` data into `table1` schema.

How can I insert data like `name-->name`, `address-->location` and `phone-->mobile`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert all values of a table into another table in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576441/insert-all-values-of-a-table-into-another-table-in-sql)

Comment: Here you are. I find another example and change link

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into table1 (name, address, phone)
select name, location, mobile from table2
```